# Show or Hide Side Menu in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I am a beginner with blazor.

Please tell me how to Show or Hide side menu of the Blazor standard template using a button.

Thank You Very Much !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best is to go with your own server, create a new Class called **ViewOptionService.cs**. This will contain the logic and work as a singleton service.
_navBarVisible will hold the status if the nav bar is hidden or not, while Toggle will change the state and NavBarClass will used to hide the div of the nav bar:

```
public class ViewOptionService
{
    private bool _navBarVisible = true;

    public Action OnChanged { get; set; }
    
    //Change state by click on the button
    public void Toggle()
    {
        _navBarVisible = !_navBarVisible;//Change
        if (OnChanged != null) OnChanged();//Callback for reload
    }

    //get additional css class for nav bar div
    public string NavBarClass
    {
        get
        {
            if (_navBarVisible) return String.Empty;//No additional css class for show nav bar
            return "d-none";//d-none class will hide the div
        }
    }
}
```

We must register ViewOptionService as a Service, so modify the **Main** in **Program.cs**:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //..
    //Add next line to register
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ViewOptionService>();

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

Now we can inject this as service and use it in **MainLayout.razor** to add a css class to the div:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject ViewOptionService ViewOption

<div class="sidebar @ViewOption.NavBarClass">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
```

We can also inject it in the **Index.razor** (or somewhere else) to add a button:

```
@page "/"
@inject ViewOptionService ViewOption

<button @onclick="ViewOption.Toggle">Hide Menu</button>
```

One final step is missing, in case the value has changed we need to reload the MainLayout.razor, so we need to add a code part to the **MainLayout**:

```
@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ViewOption.OnChanged = () => { 
            StateHasChanged();//Refresh
        };
    }
}
```

=== Edit ===

I postet full code under https://github.com/DanielHWe/Hide-Blazor-NavBar-Sample

Comment: I can't make this example to work and I don't know why...

Comment: Is it not working or not compiling? Any error messages?

Comment: Now it is working fine !

Now I think it was not working on me because I have
an WebAssembly Blazor Project that includes 3 projects :
Client, Server and Shared...

I will try again to implement your code into my project but
how I said before, I couldn't do it from the first time...

Thank You Very Much and Best Regards !

Comment: In this case it would be nice if you mark my post as answer

Comment: I was considering going for CascadingValue passing a `NavMenu` reference down approach instead of the Service implementation listed here. The problem with CascadingValue is that the render queue is not guaranteed to execute in the order you want the components to show up, therefore references may become null. As application scales, the render queue becomes harder to manage. 

So as Daniel W. says, service option is indeed the best approach.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/web-development/convert-the-standard-blazor-navigation-menu-to-a-collapsible/m-p/3753268 i find this solution and its worked for me 